# TypeORM Cannot query across one-to-many for property members

Tags: typeorm

I am new with `typeorm` and I face trouble with a `OneToMany` relationship. I have a `Person` entity which contains a `@OnetoMany` relationship to a `Member` entity and a `@ManyToOne` relationship to a `Fare` entity. I can post a new `Person` without problem but I get an error when I update an existing `Person` with the following body:

```
{"firstName":"john","lastName":"doe","fareId": 1}
```

The error is the following:

`(node:699940) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot query across one-to-many for property members`

Here is my `Person` entity:

```
import { Entity, Column, ManyToOne, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

import { Fare, Member } from "./";

@Entity()
export class Person {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({
        unique: false,
        nullable: false
    })
    firstName: string;

    @Column({
        unique: false,
        nullable: false
    })
    lastName: string;

    @Column({
        unique: false,
        nullable: true
    })
    address: string;

    @Column({
        unique: false,
        nullable: true
    })
    phone: string;

    @Column({
        unique: false,
        nullable: true
    })
    email: string;

    @OneToMany(() => Member, member => member.person)
    members: Member[];

    @ManyToOne(() => Fare, fare => fare.persons)
    fare: Fare
}
```

Here is the update part of my controller:

```
router.put('/persons/:id', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const id = +req['params']['id'];
    const person = await this._personService.readOne(id);
    if (!person) {
        res.status(400).send('Person not found')
    }

    const { lastName, firstName, address, email, phone, fareId } = req['body'];
    if (fareId) {
        const fare = await this._fareService.readOne(fareId);
        if (!fare) {
            res.status(400).send('Fare not found')
        } else {
            person.fare = fare;
        }
    }

    person.lastName = lastName ? lastName : person.lastName;
    person.firstName = firstName ? firstName : person.firstName;
    person.address = address ? address : person.address;
    person.email = email ? email : person.email;
    person.phone = phone ? phone : person.phone;

    const updatedPerson = await this._personService.update(person,id);
    res.send(updatedPerson);
});
```

and here is the update part of my `Person` service:

```
public update = async (person: Person, id: number) => {
    const updatedPerson = await this._personRepository.update(id, person);
    return updatedPerson;
}
```

would you know what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71282195/9801709