# Error: Cannot query across many-to-many for property on updating

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, many-to-many, nestjs, typeorm

I am try to update many to may relation.

```
export class CreateProductDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  description: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  name: string;

  @ApiProperty({ isArray: true })
  @IsNumber({}, { each: true })
  @IsArray()
  categoryIds: number[];
}
```

```
export class UpdateProductDto extends PartialType(CreateProductDto) {}
```

```
export class ProductsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Product)
    private productRepository: Repository<Product>,
    private categoriesService: CategoriesService,
  ) {}

  async update(id: number, updateProductDto: UpdateProductDto) {
    let categories: Category[] = undefined;
    if (updateProductDto.categoryIds) {
      categories = await Promise.all(
        updateProductDto.categoryIds.map(
          async (id) => await this.categoriesService.findOneOrFail(id),
        ),
      );
      delete updateProductDto.categoryIds;
    }
    await this.productRepository.update(
      { id },
      { ...updateProductDto, categories },
    );
    return await this.findOneOrFail(id);
  }

  async findOneOrFail(id: number) {
    const product = await this.productRepository.findOne({ id });
    if (product) {
      return product;
    }
    throw new BadRequestException(`Product is not present`);
  }
}
```

```
@Entity()
export class Product extends BaseEntity {
  @Column()
  description: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Category, (object) => object.products, {
    cascade: true,
    eager: true,
  })
  @JoinTable()
  categories: Category[];

}
```

```
@Entity()
export class Category extends BaseEntity {
  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Product, (object) => object.categories)
  products: Product[];
}
```

Finally when i try to call `ProductsService.update` with this payload it

```
"categoryIds": [ 2 ]
```

i got an error like this
`Error: Cannot query across many-to-many for property categories`

Can some please help me to update many to many

Answer (score -1):

In your Category Entity add the relation id of Product and use `save` method instead of `update` when you update your entity.

```
@Entity()
export class Category extends BaseEntity {
  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Product, (object) => object.categories)
  products: Product[];

  // Add this 

  @Column()
  productId: string;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To solve problemes like i use.

```js
async dummyUpdate(objetUpdateDto: ObjectUpdateDto): Promise<TypeReturn> {
  const { idObjectToUpdate, colum1ToUpate, colum2ToUpate } = objetUpdateDto;
  try {
    const objectToUpdate = await this.repositoryOfEntity.findOne(idObjectToUpdate);
    idObjectToUpdate.colum1ToUpate = colum1ToUpate;
    idObjectToUpdate.colum2ToUpate = colum2ToUpate;
    await this.repositoryOfEntity.save(objectToUpdate);
    return objectToUpdate,
  } catch(err) {
    throw new ConflictException("your message" + err);
  }
}
```